# The area to perimeter ratio and generalizations

Tags: geometry

I reckon (without proof) that a circle (including the interior) is the two-dimensional figure which maximizes the area-perimeter ratio.

For example, given a fixed perimeter a circle with that perimeter has $\frac{4}{\pi}$ times the area of a square  with that same perimeter. Similarly, I would assume that a sphere (or possibly a ball would be the more precise term) maximizes the volume-surface area ratio.

Thus, a natural question to ask would be that an $n$-dimensional analogue of a sphere is the "shape" in $n$-space which maximizes the ratio between whatever corresponds to "volume" and "surface area" in $n$-space.

Is this true? Proof? Counter-examples?

Edit: [It appears](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297870/prove-that-the-sphere-is-the-only-closed-surface-in-mathbbr3-that-minimize) as though even the 3-dimensional case is very non-trivial. I will then slightly alter my question: has this been proven, and if it has been proven false what are the counter examples.

Comment: Of course it is true.  Humps and bumps add more surface than volume.

Comment: Intuitively it is undoubtedly logical but I don't think intuition is very meaningful in 58-dimensions.

Comment: I don't have a rigorous argument, but it will come down to the fact that if $r$ is the (small) scale of the irregularity, $r^{57} \gg r^{58}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: @Chappers Thank you! That was very helpful.