# Given a fixed volume. Can we find the minimum surface area of any shape?

Tags: differential-geometry, area, maxima-minima

For a given fixed volume, can we find the minimum surface area of any shape?
We kind of know the minimum surface area is a sphere(restrict our problem in 3 dim space).
(correct me if the sphere is NOT a minimum surface area)

How do we prove that the sphere is the minimum surface for a given volume?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A problem on Minima. Proving sphere has minimum surface area for a given volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221307/a-problem-on-minima-proving-sphere-has-minimum-surface-area-for-a-given-volume)

Comment: This is a special case of the isoperimetric inequality, and it's a problem in the calculus of variations. But it's rather difficult. You show that the surface has constant mean curvature, and then it's a theorem of Alexandrov that a compact, smooth surface of constant mean curvature is a round sphere. (For example, you have double soap-bubbles which solve the question as well.)