# minimum surface are for a given volume

Tags: maxima-minima

How to prove that for a given enclosed volume, a sphere has minimum surface area

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is "you can't".

You've stumbled on a hard problem - well beyond 12th grade calculus: see [Prove that the sphere is the only closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that minimizes the surface area to volume ratio.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297870/prove-that-the-sphere-is-the-only-closed-surface-in-mathbbr3-that-minimize) .

The two dimensional version - the circle minimizes perimeter for a fixed area - might be accessible. Search for *isoperimetric problem* for many good links.

Comment: @ResearchEngineer I suspect you studied the problem in two dimensions (the isoperimetric problem). That's accessible, though not plain calculus.