# surface area maximisation for fixed volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, variational-analysis

It is known how $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ minimises surface area for a fixed volume, i.e.
fixing the surface area, it maximises the volume within

In Other words:

Constant-volume, surfaceArea minimisation requires constant (+1) sectional curvature of the outcome structure

BUT here is the question:

1. How to show a Constant-volume, surfaceArea MAXIMIZATION requires constant (-1) sectional curvature?

one intuitive argument follows, that fixing a volume; the surface should DEFLATE (possibly create cusps) or INFLATE depending on whether the surfaceArea has to be respectively, MAXIMISED or MINIMISED. Where deflation would cause a negative sectional curvature [or atleast the sectional curvature should be bounded by some negative number], and positive, for inflation. Also,

2. Is there a possibility to impose a metric on arbitrary compact manifold of FIXED volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and inflate or deflate (Probably the technical way to say it, is in terms of Ricci Flows) and depending on whether the surface area is minimising or maximising, it is to check the outcome metric which would indeed give atleast mean-curvature to be consecutively +ve or -ve?

I've found in a lecture by Prof. Mahan MJ, that surface area maximisation for fixed volume leads to hyperbolic structure 3D as an outcome and is the source of this question.

I am in longstanding doubt on this, since trying to learn them by myself. Therefore any clarification would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by '-ve' #] ?

Comment: I meant a negative number, which I edited

Comment: Sorry by I don't understand your notation for a negative number.

Comment: Would you kindly see the matter? How do I extremise the surface area constrained to a constant volume of a compact Riemannian 3-manifold?

Comment: All right. I will never know what "ve" means... Besides, by vain curiosity again, do you know if the same problem with one dimension less has been solved, i.e., does a circle minimizes the length of a closed curve for a fixed area (with connection to a constant negative curvature) ?

Comment: yes, But my doubt was whether this equivalently holds for 3-manifolds?

Comment: The problem of maximizing surface area with fixed volume does not lead to any "nice" surfaces, such as one with constant curvature. There are no global maxima or even local maxima, and surface area can be made arbitrarily large for any fixed volume.

Comment: but for a fixed volume there has to be some notion of an 'extent' of hyperbolicity which must increase in increasing the surface area,

Comment: And I am not asking for a particular metric on some surface rather just the conclusion that if it maximises surfaceArea-Volume ratio, one of its curvature scalars has to be upperbounded by some negative number. Is it possible?

Comment: @prikarsartam There is no such notion, to my knowledge; there are numerous ways of increasing surface area, not all of which have a "nice" effect on the curvature. Also, statements about surfaces which maximize area (or area/volume ratio) are vacuous, as these surfaces do not exist.

Comment: @prikarsartam   evidently it is http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~mahan/  at Tata, who often writes in English and often posts articles on the arxiv.  If you gave a link to the "lecture"  you have in mind, it would help.

Comment: @Kajelad  apparently this is a lecture  by http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~mahan/  at Tata, who is prolific. If we had a link to the "lecture" it would likely tell us the nature of the question above.   Also https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=Mj%2C+M   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahan_Mj

Comment: I was mentioning about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqBLnJACWYs

Comment: @prikarsartam   he also puts the lecture "slides"  on his web page,  the talk you mention gives http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~mahan/ct_gen.pdf  ,  there are 7  sets of slides available at the bottom of the page http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~mahan/  .... I don't see anything about surface area  or the word "maximal", so it must be a remark as part of one of his lectures. If you can confirm the youtube address   and then specify a few minutes in it,  perhaps we can make sense of this.   Youtube says that talk is 1:11:21, that is one hour eleven minutes 21 seconds

Comment: I think a question itself should be self sufficient irrespective of its source

Comment: Regarding your last comments: Both questions you asked are too unclear to be answerable. The first question presupposes that something is true while it is actually false (it was explained to you that area maximization with constant volume yields infinity, this does not require constant curvature). The 2nd question is utterly unclear. As far as I can tell, both questions stem from misunderstanding of what Mj was saying. My suggestion is to learn more about subjects you are interested in by reading rather than watching Youtube movies.