# Does a cone have the “minimal exposed surface area for the volume of water it contains?”

Tags: geometry, optimization

A [recent article on CNN](https://www.cnn.com/style/article/ice-stupa-sonam-wangchuk/index.html) details an idea for storing water in cold deserts as a cone of ice.

[image]

The article describes many advantages of a cone shape (easy to form, etc.), and includes this quote:

> But a cone has more desirable properties: “It has minimal exposed surface area for the volume of water it contains.”

Is this true? If so, how would you prove that of all surfaces enclosing a fixed volume underneath, a cone has the lowest surface area? I haven’t the faintest idea how to approach a minimization problem like this.

Comment: Relevant: sphere minimizes surface area to volume ratio https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297870/prove-that-the-sphere-is-the-only-closed-surface-in-mathbbr3-that-minimize But perhaps “exposed surface area” is the key phrase here, somehow.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the constraints are, but for a given volume and a given circular (unexposed) base, surely the minimal exposed surface area would be a spherical cap, not a cone..  After all, this is the shape of a soap bubble resting on a plane.